# Override MS office updates managed by your administrator

Tags: administrator, office365

In my organisation, MS office updates are managed by Administrator.

Hence, I don't' get the latest features as and when they are released by Microsoft.
I am wondering if there is a way I can override this?

[image: MS Office account screen]

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to update the MS office to latest version, even if it's locked by Administrator, change these registry keys.

navigate to: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\officeupdate`

set `officemgmtcom` to '0'

set `enableautomaticupdates` to '1'

set `hideenabledisableupdates` to '0'

And you should see the option to update your office apps.

In case you Don't know how to change registry,
`press start > type regedit > launch regedit`

#### This is how your final state should look like.

[image: Final Regedit]

Comment: Don't expect your IT support team to come to your aid when you have an issue. They will likely suggest you revert back to the version they do support, which is why the group policy is there in the first place.

Comment: If the admin use group policy to change the update source, such as a shared folder with the update files the admin download, the Office may not be updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the update was disable with the setup. I only had to change this:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration

OfficeMgmtCOM = False

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\cloud\office\16.0\Common\officeupdate` is the current location.  Please update. Sorry I cannot comment yet.
Worked for me.  Removed update* keys which had corp info, and changed as per above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\cloud" folder from the registry (make back-up).

It seems new installed systemens do not have these folder. But the folder does contain some policies on how, and what, to update Office 365 Apps.

I had the same problem, and after removing this, the user can update Office as they like to the new version.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this myself as a office 365 user with a much less invasive method.

1. Go to Office.com, login with your company credentials.
2. Top right of the page click Install Office > Office 365 Apps
3. Run the OfficeSetup.exe it downloads.

This updated my machine to a much newer version of office in 5 minutes, despite not being offered it in Windows/Microsoft update, Software Center or the update page inside Office apps.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I did a little bit of research and found out that what Patrick suggested was the right way. Office newest installer creates both registry keys and it making the OfficeC2RCom go nuts. After testing and deleting the cloud and second one without cloud path, i come to find that the cloud is unnecessary there. If you deleted one then made the registry to the other one  value 0, restarted the service,changed back the value to 1 and then also restarted the service then everything looks great.
Maybe this comment is irrelevant but hope someone gets something from it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159079)